# How to "distribute" memcached?

Tags: linux, unix, memory, memcached, cache

I know how to install and use memcached on one server. But I heard you can "distribute it"?

How does that work, and how can I enable that feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcached sharding happens in the client library -- so you just tell your client library to use multiple memcached instances, and it sorts out all the details itself.